# React `root.render()` does not render on call

Tags: reactjs

I want to immidiately render some react node to dom node. Below is my code with currently working (depreciated) method (`dom`) and new one which unfortunately does not render `content` immidiately on call (`domNew`).

```
      const dom = document.createElement('div');
      const content = <Content editor={editorRef.current} />;
      render(content, dom); // react-dom

      const domNew = document.createElement('div');
      const root = createRoot(domNew);
      root.render(content); // react-dom/client
```

How to render it on call? I ahve to render it on call because then other library uses it to calculate some positioning

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please validate if you have imported the script in index.html and if there is a div with id=root

```
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="module" src="/src/index.tsx"></script>
```

Post that you can use this to render.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
root.render(
  <p>Hello World</p>
)
```

Comment: doesnt work, I need to render content imidiately after calling `render` which is not the case when using `createRoot`.